Temenos Printing Error on AIX: Unsupported lpr Flags (-J and -o) with Semeru Runtime
I'm running a Temenos application on an AIX 7.3 system configured with the AIX spooler. The lpr command works fine when tested manually. However, when the application attempts to print using Java's java.io.PrintService API, I encounter the following error:
java.io.IOException: error=254 running: '/usr/bin/lpr' '-PTESTPRN2' '-J Java Printing' '-o job-sheets=standard' '/tmp/javaprint13160595099572358650'  
usage: lpr [-fghjlmnprs] [-PPrinter] [-#NumberCopies] [-CClass]  
           [-JJob] [-TTitle] [-iNumberColumns] [-wWidth] [Filename ...]  

It seems the Java code, triggered by Temenos, generates an lpr command with flags (-J and -o) that are not supported by the AIX lpr implementation. The spooler itself is set up correctly and prints without issues when commands are executed manually:
lpr -PTESTPRN2 /etc/hosts

What I've tried:

Considered downgrading to Java 8, as it might generate compatible
lpr commands and lpr with -j and -o works fine, but Java 11 is currently installed. Note:application can't run on java8
The lpr command works fine when executed manually without unsupported flags (e.g., lpr -PTESTPRN2 /path/to/file).
Thought about creating a wrapper script to translate unsupported
flags into AIX-compatible ones, but I'm unsure how to integrate it
with Temenos.
Write sample Java code that uses JPS to print and got same error with java11 but works on java8.
Run the sample Java code with wrapper script. 
It works, but still Temenos gave the same error.

Sample Java Code for Testing
import javax.print.*;
import javax.print.attribute.*;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PrintHostsFileWithQueue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String printerName = "TESTPRN2"; // Replace with your print queue name

        try {
            // Specify the file to print
            File file = new File("/etc/hosts");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                System.out.println("The file /etc/hosts does not exist.");
                return;
            }

            // Create a FileInputStream for the file
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            // Define the document flavor (plain text)
            DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.TEXT_PLAIN_UTF_8;
            PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            attributes.add(new Copies(1)); // Number of copies
            attributes.add(new JobSheets(JobSheets.NONE, JobSheets.NONE));

            // Get all available print services
            PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, null);

            // Find the specified print queue
            PrintService selectedService = null;
            for (PrintService service : printServices) {
                if (service.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(printerName)) {
                    selectedService = service;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (selectedService == null) {
                System.out.println("Printer with name '" + printerName + "' not found.");
                fis.close();
                return;
            }

            // Create a print job
            DocPrintJob printJob = selectedService.createPrintJob();

            // Create a Doc object wrapping the input stream
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, null);

            // Print the document
            printJob.print(doc, null);

            System.out.println("Printing /etc/hosts to printer: " + printerName);
            fis.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (PrintException e) {
            System.out.println("Error during printing: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error closing the file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

Wrapper Script
#!/bin/bash

# Step 1: Backup the existing lpr binary
if [ -f /usr/bin/lpr ]; then
    echo "Backing up the existing /usr/bin/lpr..."
     mv /usr/bin/lpr /usr/bin/lpr.original
else
    echo "/usr/bin/lpr does not exist. Exiting."
    exit 1
fi

# Step 2: Create the new lpr wrapper script
echo "Creating the new /usr/bin/lpr wrapper script..."

cat <<'EOF' | tee /usr/bin/lpr > /dev/null
#!/bin/bash
# Remove unsupported options and pass others to the original lpr
ARGS=()
for arg in "$@"; do
    case "$arg" in
        -o*|*-J*) ;; # Ignore unsupported options
        *) ARGS+=("$arg") ;;
    esac
done
/usr/bin/lpr.original "${ARGS[@]}"
EOF

# Step 3: Make the new script executable
echo "Making /usr/bin/lpr executable..."
chmod +x /usr/bin/lpr

# Step 4: Confirm the change
echo "lpr wrapper script has been created and is now executable."
echo "Test the print command to confirm it's working."


(1) Why do you say that -J is unsupported when the usage message lists [-JJOB]? (1b) Have you tried running a command with -J (e.g., '-J Java Printing')? (2) Show us your wrapper script, not a script that you use to create the wrapper script, unless you have a question about the installation script. (2b) Does the installation script work? (2c) The installation script is clumsy. If you run it a second time, it will clobber your backup copy of the lpr binary. You should test whether /usr/bin/lpr.original exists, and/or use mv -n if your version of mv supports it.  … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) …  (2d) Have you examined the wrapper script as created by the installation script (to verify that it got created correctly)?   (2e) What happens if you run your wrapper script (e.g., with the command you show from the java.io.IOException error)?   (2f) Does your wrapper script run when you run your Java program?   (If you’re not sure; add logging; e.g., echo "$(date) $0 $*" >> "$HOME/lpr.wrapper.log".)   (2g) And add more logging in general; e.g., exactly what command does it run in the end?  … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) …  (2h) Why are you looking for “*-J*”?   That would cause an argument of “-PBLUE-JAY” to be rejected as invalid.

hello there -j flag is supported though i have skip -j and -o flag in wrapper script. the problem is in -o flag. when running wrapper script and giving command lpr with -J and -o flag print works fine but application give same error. yes wrapper script run always it's concept is like skip those unsupported flag and call orignal lpr to print. and there is no such wrapper script bydefault i just create bash script to skip flag and name it as wrapper script.

You can use $PATH to solve your problem.
mkdir $HOME/earlybin

then, create an executable script in $HOME/earlybin/lpr that passes all the parameters, except the toxic ones to /usr/bin/lpr.
Then, in your startup file (~/.bashrc) add:
PATH=$HOME/earlybin:$PATH

